# ImageViews shrink in size when setting RelativeLayout Param height

Tags: java, android

I have an activity which is acting like a bottom sheet. I have it set so the user can drag it with their finger and it will move accordingly. All works well except when the bottomsheet is dragged whichever icon is closest to the bottom gets resized instead of just dropping off the screen. This creates a weird and unwanted effect.

Here is a picture of what is happening:

[image: Problem]

Here is the method for resizing:

```
public void setAdjustableTouchListener() {
        full.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mDragStartY = event.getY();
                        mDraggingStarted = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                        mPointerOffset = event.getRawY() + main.getMeasuredHeight();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (mDragStartY < (event.getY() + TAP_DRIFT_TOLERANCE) && mDragStartY > (event.getY() - TAP_DRIFT_TOLERANCE)
                                && ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mDraggingStarted) < SINGLE_TAP_MAX_TIME)) {
                            result = "Dismissed";
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            if (main.getMeasuredHeight() > (viewConversion + heightDifference)) {
                                ResizeAnimation a = new ResizeAnimation(main);
                                a.setDuration(500);
                                a.setParams(main.getMeasuredHeight(), extendedViewHeight);
                                main.startAnimation(a);
                            } else if (main.getMeasuredHeight() < (viewConversion + heightDifference)
                                    && main.getMeasuredHeight() > viewConversion) {
                                ResizeAnimation a = new ResizeAnimation(main);
                                a.setDuration(500);
                                a.setParams(main.getMeasuredHeight(), viewConversion);
                                main.startAnimation(a);
                            } else if (main.getMeasuredHeight() < viewConversion && main.getMeasuredHeight() > (viewConversion / 2)) {
                                ResizeAnimation a = new ResizeAnimation(main);
                                a.setDuration(500);
                                a.setParams(main.getMeasuredHeight(), viewConversion);
                                main.startAnimation(a);
                            } else {
                                result = "Dismissed";
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mPointerOffset - event.getRawY() < extendedViewHeight)
                            setPrimaryContentHeight((int) (mPointerOffset - event.getRawY()));
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: That changed it but the icons still have a weird effect when hiding. I will try to mess around with the different ScaleType options and see if I can find one that works

Comment: ok, MATRIX worked but it made all the images appear really weird. I am going to go with FIT_END since it has a cool effect and at least makes it work. Thanks!